# Match Pattern, save it in a variable and append it at the end of line using sed/awk/grep

Tags: awk, sed

This is a problem I have been grappling for last 4 days. I read tutorials on google and on SOF but none could help me. I am throwing it out as a problem here so that others could attempt and help me solve it. I have already solved it using crude methods but thinking if there is a smarter way. So there is a file with list of ball bearings and its attributes. It looks like this:

```
<li class="odd  first">
     <a href="/productcatalogue/prodlink.html?lang=en&amp;imperial=false&amp;prodid=1310003030&amp;pubid=21&amp;WT.oss=&amp;WT.z_oss_boost=0&amp;WT.z_oss_ref=ProductSearch&amp;WT.z_oss_rank=1">33030</a>
    |<strong>Product category: </strong> <a href="/productcatalogue/prodlink.html?lang=en&amp;imperial=false&amp;prodid=1310003030&amp;pubid=21&amp;WT.oss=&amp;WT.z_oss_boost=0&amp;WT.z_oss_ref=ProductSearch&amp;WT.z_oss_rank=1&amp;isTableView=true" class="product-table-link">Tapered roller bearings single row</a>

        |<strong>Width: </strong> 59 mm
        |<strong>Bore diameter: </strong> 150 mm
        |<strong>Outside diameter: </strong> 225 mm
        |<strong>Source: </strong> -


        |<strong>Limiting speed: </strong> 2600 r/min
        |<strong>Reference speed: </strong> 2000 r/min


</li>
<li class="even ">
     <a href="/productcatalogue/prodlink.html?lang=en&amp;imperial=false&amp;prodid=1310000230&amp;pubid=21&amp;WT.oss=&amp;WT.z_oss_boost=0&amp;WT.z_oss_ref=ProductSearch&amp;WT.z_oss_rank=2">30230</a>
    |<strong>Product category: </strong> <a href="/productcatalogue/prodlink.html?lang=en&amp;imperial=false&amp;prodid=1310000230&amp;pubid=21&amp;WT.oss=&amp;WT.z_oss_boost=0&amp;WT.z_oss_ref=ProductSearch&amp;WT.z_oss_rank=2&amp;isTableView=true" class="product-table-link">Tapered roller bearings single row</a>

        |<strong>Width: </strong> 49 mm
        |<strong>Bore diameter: </strong> 150 mm
        |<strong>Outside diameter: </strong> 270 mm
        |<strong>Source: </strong> -


        |<strong>Limiting speed: </strong> 2400 r/min
        |<strong>Reference speed: </strong> 1800 r/min


</li>
<li class="odd  ">
     <a href="/productcatalogue/prodlink.html?lang=en&amp;imperial=false&amp;prodid=1310003024&amp;pubid=21&amp;WT.oss=&amp;WT.z_oss_boost=0&amp;WT.z_oss_ref=ProductSearch&amp;WT.z_oss_rank=3">33024</a>
    |<strong>Product category: </strong> <a href="/productcatalogue/prodlink.html?lang=en&amp;imperial=false&amp;prodid=1310003024&amp;pubid=21&amp;WT.oss=&amp;WT.z_oss_boost=0&amp;WT.z_oss_ref=ProductSearch&amp;WT.z_oss_rank=3&amp;isTableView=true" class="product-table-link">Tapered roller bearings single row</a>

        |<strong>Width: </strong> 48 mm
        |<strong>Bore diameter: </strong> 120 mm
        |<strong>Outside diameter: </strong> 180 mm
        |<strong>Source: </strong> -


        |<strong>Limiting speed: </strong> 3400 r/min
        |<strong>Reference speed: </strong> 2600 r/min


</li>
<li class="even ">
     <a href="/productcatalogue/prodlink.html?lang=en&amp;imperial=false&amp;prodid=1310003022&amp;pubid=21&amp;WT.oss=&amp;WT.z_oss_boost=0&amp;WT.z_oss_ref=ProductSearch&amp;WT.z_oss_rank=4">33022</a>
    |<strong>Product category: </strong> <a href="/productcatalogue/prodlink.html?lang=en&amp;imperial=false&amp;prodid=1310003022&amp;pubid=21&amp;WT.oss=&amp;WT.z_oss_boost=0&amp;WT.z_oss_ref=ProductSearch&amp;WT.z_oss_rank=4&amp;isTableView=true" class="product-table-link">Tapered roller bearings single row</a>

        |<strong>Width: </strong> 47 mm
        |<strong>Bore diameter: </strong> 110 mm
        |<strong>Outside diameter: </strong> 170 mm
        |<strong>Source: </strong> -


        |<strong>Limiting speed: </strong> 3600 r/min
        |<strong>Reference speed: </strong> 2600 r/min


</li>
<li class="odd  ">
     <a href="/productcatalogue/prodlink.html?lang=en&amp;imperial=false&amp;prodid=1310003220&amp;pubid=21&amp;WT.oss=&amp;WT.z_oss_boost=0&amp;WT.z_oss_ref=ProductSearch&amp;WT.z_oss_rank=5">33220</a>
    |<strong>Product category: </strong> <a href="/productcatalogue/prodlink.html?lang=en&amp;imperial=false&amp;prodid=1310003220&amp;pubid=21&amp;WT.oss=&amp;WT.z_oss_boost=0&amp;WT.z_oss_ref=ProductSearch&amp;WT.z_oss_rank=5&amp;isTableView=true" class="product-table-link">Tapered roller bearings single row</a>

        |<strong>Width: </strong> 63 mm
        |<strong>Bore diameter: </strong> 100 mm
        |<strong>Outside diameter: </strong> 180 mm
        |<strong>Source: </strong> -


        |<strong>Limiting speed: </strong> 3600 r/min
        |<strong>Reference speed: </strong> 2400 r/min              
</li>
```

Now if you look at the response of the HTML (and not the html itself). I want to parse it, extract a parameter which is there in the href link  (in the first entry, there is prodid parameter in the href link, prodid=1310003030). If its possible I want to append the entire link at the end of each line.

I want to extract it and append at the end of EACH line so the entries look like this.

```
33030 |Product category: Tapered roller bearings single row |Width: 59 mm |Bore diameter: 150 mm |Outside diameter: 225 mm |Source: - |Limiting speed: 2600 r/min |Reference speed: 2000 r/min | 1310003030 
30230 |Product category: Tapered roller bearings single row |Width: 49 mm |Bore diameter: 150 mm |Outside diameter: 270 mm |Source: - |Limiting speed: 2400 r/min |Reference speed: 1800 r/min | 1310000230 
33024 |Product category: Tapered roller bearings single row |Width: 48 mm |Bore diameter: 120 mm |Outside diameter: 180 mm |Source: - |Limiting speed: 3400 r/min |Reference speed: 2600 r/min | 1310003024 
33022 |Product category: Tapered roller bearings single row |Width: 47 mm |Bore diameter: 110 mm |Outside diameter: 170 mm |Source: - |Limiting speed: 3600 r/min |Reference speed: 2600 r/min | 1310003022
```

Comment: Scraping HTML into machine-readable output is an exercise in futility.  See if you could connect to whatever produced that HTML in the first place.

Comment: Well I am trying to scrape some data from a website for my own analysis. So I don't have control over the source.

Comment: save your time with correct tool, try `xmllint` to do the job

Answer (score 0):

This is the sed version. I have to admit it's not that easy to exchange the order of words on different lines using `sed`;

```
sed -nre '
/^ *<a/{
    h;s/^.*prodid=([0-9]+).*$/ |\1/;x;s_^.*>([0-9]+)</a.*$_\1_
    :back
    N
    s/\n.*(Product category:).*\">(.*)<.*$/ |\1 \2/
    s_\n.*strong>(.*)</strong>(.*)$_ |\1 \2_
    /<\/li>$/ !bback
    /<\/li>$/ {
        s/<\/li>$//;G;s/\n//g;s/  */ /g;p
    }
}
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The UNIX tool for general purpose text manipulation is `awk`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "[[:space:]]*<[^>]+>[[:space:]]*"
    OFS = " |"
}

/^[[:space:]]*<a href/{
    split($0,a,/.*prodid=|&.*/)
    prodid = a[2]
    prodnr = $(NF-1)
}

/<strong>/ {
    name  = $2
    value = ($NF == "" ? $(NF-1) : $NF)
    sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"",value)
    n2v[name] = value
    if (!seen[name]++) {
        names[++numNames] = name
    }
}

/<\/li>/ {
    printf "%s%s", prodnr, OFS
    for (nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames; nameNr++) {
        name  = names[nameNr]
        value = n2v[name]
        printf "%s %s%s", name, value, OFS
    }
    print " " prodid
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
33030 |Product category: Tapered roller bearings single row |Width: 59 mm |Bore diameter: 150 mm |Outside diameter: 225 mm |Source: - |Limiting speed: 2600 r/min |Reference speed: 2000 r/min | 1310003030
30230 |Product category: Tapered roller bearings single row |Width: 49 mm |Bore diameter: 150 mm |Outside diameter: 270 mm |Source: - |Limiting speed: 2400 r/min |Reference speed: 1800 r/min | 1310000230
33024 |Product category: Tapered roller bearings single row |Width: 48 mm |Bore diameter: 120 mm |Outside diameter: 180 mm |Source: - |Limiting speed: 3400 r/min |Reference speed: 2600 r/min | 1310003024
33022 |Product category: Tapered roller bearings single row |Width: 47 mm |Bore diameter: 110 mm |Outside diameter: 170 mm |Source: - |Limiting speed: 3600 r/min |Reference speed: 2600 r/min | 1310003022
33220 |Product category: Tapered roller bearings single row |Width: 63 mm |Bore diameter: 100 mm |Outside diameter: 180 mm |Source: - |Limiting speed: 3600 r/min |Reference speed: 2400 r/min | 1310003220
```